# Terraform - How to convert lists into map (How to fetch AMI tags using terraform)

Tags: terraform, jq, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws, hcl

I am trying to fetch the tags of AMI using AWS CLI and want to reuse the values from the output.
I have a terraform code below which is returning outputs in string format(Maybe not sure of format) which I want to convert into a map object.

```
variable "ami" {
  default = "ami-xxxx"
}

locals {
  tags = {
  "platform"    = lookup(data.local_file.read_tags.content, "platform", "") #Expecting to get platform from Map of read_tags
  }
}

data "template_file" "log_name" {
  template = "${path.module}/output.log"
}

resource "null_resource" "ami_tags" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws ec2 describe-tags --filters Name=resource-id,Values=${var.ami} --query Tags[*].[Key,Value] > ${data.template_file.log_name.rendered}"
  }
}

data "local_file" "read_tags" {
  filename = "${data.template_file.log_name.rendered}"
  depends_on = ["null_resource.ami_tags"]
}

output "tags" {
  value = local.tags
}

output "cli-output-tags" {
  value = "${concat(data.local_file.read_tags.content)}"
}
```

output of **cli-output-tags** is below:

```
[
    [
        "ENV",
        "DEV"
    ],
    [
        "Name",
        "Base-AMI"
    ],
    [
        "platform",
        "Linux"
    ]
]
```

How can I convert this output into Map as below using terraform/(jq command), or is there any other way to fetch required values directly from **cli-output-tags** output:

```
{
ENV  = "DEV",
Name = "Base-AMI",
platform = "Linux"
}
```

I have also tried changing the CLI command a bit like below but still not able to fetch values as expected:

```
'Tags[].{Key:Key,Value:Value}'
```

Resulted below output:

```
[
    {
        "Key": "ENV",
        "Value": "DEV"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "Base-AMI"
    },
    {
        "Key": "platform",
        "Value": "Linux"
    }
]
```

Comment: Also you could use `terraform output -json cli-output-tags` from console.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the [`aws_ami` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ami) for this?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR aws_ami data resource does't take AMI id as an input attribute.

Comment: That's not true. It can take a `filter` argument that uses one of the filters described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html which can include `image-id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [zipmap](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/zipmap.html):

```
output "cli-output-tags" {
  value = zipmap(
        jsondecode(data.local_file.read_tags.content)[*][0],
        jsondecode(data.local_file.read_tags.content)[*][1]
      )         
}
```

The code first changes string data from your file to json, then
gets all first elements `[*][0]` (same for second elements `[*][1]`), and zips them into map.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Simply Awsome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I convert this output into Map as below

One way would be to use jq as follows (assuming `cli-output-tags` is the name of the file holding the JSON array of arrays):

```
jq -r -f '"{", (.[] | "\(.[0]) = \"\(.[1])\""), "}"' cli-output-tags
```